# Two column page with fieldsets

Tags: html, css

I don't know where to begin learning about doing such a layout without tables, or at most one two column table as a simple container.  Where should I start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after seeing your comment about you looking for a layout with two columns of fieldsets, I went and wrote up this one without the use of tables:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Two Column Fieldsets</title>

<style>
html, body
{
  background: #156;
  text-align: center;
}

#container
{
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px #222 solid;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  width: 700px;
}

#container form
{
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label
{
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
}

.singleRow
{
  float: left;
  width: 322px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <form action="">
    <fieldset class="singleRow">
      <label for="1">Text:</label>
      <input id="1" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="singleRow">
      <label for="2">Text:</label>
      <input id="2" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </fieldset>  
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Most of the styles are just to make it line up nice and centered and to provide some contrast. The way to get two columns is to float both fieldsets left. Each fieldset has a class called .singleRow, whose only *important* style is `float: left;` (the width is in there to make them line up nicely). By floating both of the elements (in this case fieldsets, but they could be `div`s `li`s, any element) left, and making sure their combined widths are less than the width of their container, you can achieve a nice two-column layout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for a most erudite answer @Hooray!  I'll test it out a bit later.